# What is the best way to create an object from each element in a python (numpy) array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, oop, numpy-ndarray

I have an array of numbers:

```
num_arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
```

I need to transform each number into an object:

```
class MyObj:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
```

What would be the best way to do that? Is there a way to do it without using loops?

Comment: You need to use `MyObj(i)` for each `i` in the array, same as if it were a list.  You want to use `MyObj` 6 times to make 6 instances.  So some sort of loop is required.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html#numpy-nditer

Comment: What type do you want `x` to be?

Comment: @d.b, `np.nditer` rarely helps.  It's still a python level iteration, with some complications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To map over a numpy array, there is np.vectorize

```py
class MyObj:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x

num_arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
vfunc = np.vectorize(MyObj)
result = vfunc(num_arr)
```

**Edit**:

vectorize is not for performance but for convenience

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html

> The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.

Comment: Does `np.vectorize` improve anything?  Speed, convenience etc?

Comment: @hpaulj It [appears](https://tio.run/##bY1dasMwEITf9xT7qAURmr8WCjlCyAGMEYoj0y2yLCTZRLm8I9splNJ92t2Zb8bn9NW7/TRx5/uQ0A2dz6gjOg/QWB0jnvPl@v0JWOZmWlSKHSelRDS2lXinVZpn/mxGbfGEd4ASpXQI5XB@UxadRbWVO7mXB3mU7/KjJhjbwTWrYzRN6gM/jFgKCYKJg01FXEziFUfgA7skUvZGrJbqrZ5biQB0sVcLL5iw7QMyssMXW/9m9R/Mckyi036tlz8M0f/QND0B) to produce Python ints, which I think is better (feels weird to store numpy ints).

Comment: The list comprehension on `num_arr` passes `np.int` values to the `MyObj`.  The `np.vectorize` passes scalar elements, in this case Python int, to the class.  The list comprehension would be faster if `num_arr` was a list rather than a numpy array.  Creating an array of objects doesn't have significant advantages of a list of the same.

Comment: Sometimes it's a good idea to iterate on `arr.tolist()` rather than `arr` itself.  `tolist` is relatively efficient, and iterating on a list is faster.  And in a case like this it means a `int` gets passed to the class constructor.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map` but the performance enhancement is not significant.

```
import numpy as np

class MyObj:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x

n = 100000
num_arr = np.arange(n)

%timeit -n 10 -r 7 np.array([MyObj(i) for i in num_arr])
> 167 ms ± 1.97 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit -n 10 -r 7 np.array(list(map(MyObj, num_arr)))
> 163 ms ± 1.74 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

The method of @Faulheit is faster than these two methods. (Therefore, I would recommend you to accept his/her answer if you are satisfied with this result.)

```
vfunc = np.vectorize(MyObj)
%timeit -n 10 -r 7 vfunc(num_arr)
> 34.4 ms ± 813 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Additional tests are done for small lists as @hpaulj suggested.

```
n = 5

%timeit -n 10 -r 7 np.array([MyObj(i) for i in num_arr])
> 11.2 µs ± 2.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit -n 10 -r 7 np.array(list(map(MyObj, num_arr)))
> 9.91 µs ± 837 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit -n 10 -r 7 vfunc(num_arr)
> 26.8 µs ± 9.65 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

```
n = 100

%timeit -n 10 -r 7 np.array([MyObj(i) for i in num_arr])
> 176 µs ± 42 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit -n 10 -r 7 np.array(list(map(MyObj, num_arr)))
> 160 µs ± 8.36 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit -n 10 -r 7 vfunc(num_arr)
> 53.7 µs ± 13.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: It's the `np.array(...)` wrapper that consumes most time; the list comprehension runs about the same as the `vectorized` case.  `vectorized` used to run consistently slower; but recent changes have apparently improved its performance.

Comment: What about the comment from @d.b ?
Does the np.diter improve anything?
Can you also add it to the comparison?

Comment: Since we are returning an object dtype array, `np.frompyfunc(MyObj, 1,1)` should do about the same as `np.vectorize`.

Comment: @AlonBA This is the first time I heard about `np.diter`. You can create a similar code and do the benchmark if you want.

Comment: @AlonBA. I added a `nditer` case - it  is complex and slower.

Answer (score 1):

Someone suggested using `np.nditer`.  Here's a call that works.  Note that the time is worse.  It's also a lot more complex to use.

```
In [153]: %%timeit
     ...: it = np.nditer((num_arr,None), flags=('refs_ok',), op_flags=(('readonly',), ('writeonly','allocate')), op_dtypes=(int,object))
     ...: with it:
     ...:     for (a,b) in it:
     ...:        b[...] = MyObj(a.item())
     ...:     res = it.operands[1]
376 ms ± 9.74 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [154]: timeit vfunc(num_arr)
39.9 ms ± 974 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [155]: timeit np.array([MyObj(i) for i in num_arr.tolist()])
256 ms ± 4.28 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```